# Quick way to make animated gif ?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, gimp, gif, animation, animated-gif

I want to make an animated gif of a van png moving from one point on a google maps map to another point on the map.

I could add each point, separarely, but it would take hours.

Is there an intelligent/fast/free way to do this ?

e.g a gif of this ambulance going from Snelling to Merced.[image]

[image: ambulance]

Answer (score 0):

You need to draw a line - the path your vehicle will follow.

[Google Web Designer](https://www.google.com/webdesigner/) could do that - it's free. Here is a [howto](https://support.google.com/webdesigner/answer/7411704?hl=en).